# Parse Server REST request for all related objects

Tags: rest, parse-platform, relationship, parse-server

I'm very new using the Parse Server. 
I have a class, Book,  that contains a field, categories. This field is a relation that points to instances of the class Category. I want to perform a Rest request that retrieves all categories related for all Books, but I can't figure out how to make it work.
Reading a Parse REST API I found how to obtain a list of categories from one Book object using:

```
http://138.197.99.140:1337/parse/classes/Category?where={"$relatedTo":{"object":{"__type":"Pointer","className":"Book","objectId":"iQmxrzPava"},"key":"categories"}}
```

It works but I don’t have any information about:

1. How obtain just a list of related categories to all Books
2. How to obtain  a Book list that have relation with a particular category

REST API have information about AddRelation and RemoveRelation, but I can't find any info about get objects related.

Thanks .

Comment: take a look at the [Relation Queries](http://docs.parseplatform.org/rest/guide/#relational-queries) section of the guide and then find the section on querying relations.  You're going to use the `$relatedTo` operator.

Comment: I've asked similar question recently. Wonder how did you progress with your issue? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49838020/rest-query-to-get-all-roles-for-particular-user-from-parse-server