# REST query to get all roles for particular user from parse server

Tags: parse-server

How to create a REST query to get all roles assigned to a user?

As this is many to many relation in the opposite direction the regular `$relatedTo` operator seems to be not enough...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

finally I found the solution which seems to be much easier than I was afraid of :) As I found similar questions on SO and github I hope it will help others.

the `curl` query to get all the roles directly assigned to a user is:

```
curl -X GET \
  -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: ${APPLICATION_ID}" \
  -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: ${REST_API_KEY}" \
  https://parseapi.back4app.com/roles \
  --data-urlencode \
  'where={"users":{"__type":"Pointer","className":"_User","objectId":"<objectId>"}}'
```

Comment: God blesses you. Spent a couple of hours trying to do something like `{{baseUrl}}/users?where={"$relatedTo":{"object":{"__type":"Pointer","className":"_Role","objectId":"<role_objectId>"},"key":"users"}}`, which is not working by some reason.. Maybe the statement that docs is outdated is right. Thank you

Comment: Also got screwed by the REST parse documentation in a similar way. This answer does work, would love to know how to use the $relatedTo thing or find out if deprecated.